# Android User Define Location Library

Tags: android, location

Is possible to create a new library (which is Location Library) in Android?
If yes, please explain How to create user define Location Library.
if No, please tell me how to add my new location in google location map?

Comment: Why do you need to create a new location library in the first place? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to make my own location library according to me....

Comment: You would need access to the raw GPS data, which is not possible as far as I know. And frankly, you shouldn't ever need a custom location library. If the functionality provided to you by the Google Location Services isn't enough, you're doing something wrong